# Creating table at SQL developer despite making sure the code is correct

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to using SQL developer, I have tried to create a simple table but keep recieving a synatx error.
I have written :

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
    id Int(11),
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(60),
    adress VARCHAR(60),
    phone VARCHAR(8)
);
```

I keep recieving :
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Can someone tell me what's wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

```
  CREATE TABLE customer
  (
    id NUMBER(4),
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(60),
    adress VARCHAR(60),
    phone VARCHAR(8) 
  );
```

OR

```
  CREATE TABLE customer
  (
    id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(60),
    adress VARCHAR(60),
    phone VARCHAR(8) 
  );
```

Comment: That's not true; Oracle supports INT datatype (but not with precision).

Comment: sorry, I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

It is just that `INT` - if used in Oracle - doesn't allow precision. So, instead of `int(11)`, use `int` alone:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE customer
  2  (
  3     id           INT,
  4     first_name   VARCHAR (30),
  5     last_name    VARCHAR (30),
  6     email        VARCHAR (60),
  7     adress       VARCHAR (60),
  8     phone        VARCHAR (8)
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

If you want to include precision, then use `number(11)`.